# How to compute probability of event occurring with multiple CDFs

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose there are two independent processes each resulting in the same event occurring and we are at time t=0.

The first process says with uniform probability the event will occur between the 4sec and 12sec mark ie linear CDF with expectation at t=8sec.

The second process says the event will occur with 100% probability at t=10sec ie step function CDF.

What time will the event most likely occur?

Comment: Do you have equally likely confidence in both assessment of the likelihood of the event?

Comment: yes both are ongoing processes, if the event does not occur from the first process at the t=10sec mark it will definitely occur by the second process

Comment: So if you have equal faith, then you know that the probability of the event occurring at time $t=10$ is $0.5$. What about any other fixed time point $t$? If the event does not occur at time $t=10$, then the first assessment is correct. What does the fact that the relevant CDF is continuous tell you about point probabilities?

Comment: Are you saying P[e1] = 0.5 and p[e2] = 0.5 thus p[e]. = 0.5*p[e1] + 0.5*p[e2] result in t = 0.5*8sec + 0.5*10sec = 9sec

Comment: Indeed. But here you have calculated the expected value. Is the the time the event is most likely to occur? What is for example the probability that the event occurs exactly at time $t=5$ or $t=11$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the time of occurrence of the event of interest.

If we have equal confidence in both assessments, then by the law of total expectation,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X] = 0.5 \cdot 8 + 0.5 \cdot 10 = 9.
\end{align*}

But the question asks "What time will the event most likely occur?" Note that $\mathbb{P}(X=9) = 0$, since the cumulative distribution function of $X$ is continuous around $t=9$. Actually, the cumulative distribution function of $X$ is continuous on $(-\infty,10) \cup (10,\infty)$, that is in every point except $t=10$. Thus a better answer may be $t=10$, since $\mathbb{P}(X = 10) = 0.5$ while $\mathbb{P}(X=t) = 0$ for all $t\neq 10$.

Comment: I'm not sure this fully answers the question. It seems to result in more questions.

Comment: What do you not understand?